# Silverlight- How to create a content controller for selectable text

Tags: silverlight, ivalueconverter

all. I have ContentControl within my project that is bound to a property that returns a string with HTML syntax.

Control Xaml

```
 <ContentControl Height="48"
         Margin="100,56,223,0"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Content="{Binding HitContext,
         Converter={StaticResource FormatConverter},
         Mode=TwoWay}"
         Foreground="White" />
```

You'll notice that I have a Converter property on this control. In essences I evaluate the string when it is returned and strip out the html and replace it with xaml to highlight keywords within the return.

Here is the Format converter code:

```
public class HighlightConverter : IValueConverter
{
    ///<summary>
    ///Converter class used to evaluate and highlight context string results
    ///</summary>
    ///
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string str = value.ToString();

        str = str.Replace("&", "&amp;");
        str = str.Replace("<fragment>", "  ");
        str = str.Replace("</fragment>", "  ");
        str = str.Replace("<hilight>", "<Run Foreground=\"Gold\" FontWeight=\"ExtraBold\" FontSize=\"13\">");
        str = str.Replace("</hilight>", "</Run>");
        return XamlReader.Load("<TextBlock xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" TextWrapping=\"Wrap\" >" + str + "</TextBlock>");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

So far this works fine. The string is rendered in the view and words that had the tags "hilight" are converted over to render out a highlighted word within the control as a xaml syntax. You can also see other cleanup such as removing the fragment tag and ampersand.

Where I am running into issue is that I need to be able to select the text from the control at runtime. While a TextBox is normally used when you need to select text from the UI it does not support the Run class so I cannot pass the highlight formatting to UIelement.  I've also tried to use a RichTextBox but I have received a xaml parsing error stating that the control cannot be created.

I did see one link on stackoverflow and silvelright.net with a similar issue which the user suggested applying a style to the textblock. However since this is being rendered within a ContentControl the style could not be set.

So far I've tried using ViewScroller, Textbox, and RichTextBox which have all failed due to parsing errors when rendered.

I'm not even sure if this is feasible given that I am highlighting text and need to select it as well. I'd welcome any suggestions or ideas.

Thank you,

Comment: A small sample of your input "HTML" (which isn't html at all really is it?) would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show some formatted text that is also selectable.  The correct control for this is the `RichTextBox`.  I suspect that in your original attempt to use the `RichTextBox` you failed to include your final content string in a `<Paragraph>..</Paragraph>` element.  `RichTextBox` holds a collection of `Block` elements like `Paragraph` each of which then contain text runs.

The following mod of your code works:-

```
public class HighlightConverter : IValueConverter
{
    ///<summary>
    ///Converter class used to evaluate and highlight context string results
    ///</summary>
    ///
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string str = value.ToString();

        str = str.Replace("&", "&amp;");
        str = str.Replace("<fragment>", "  ");
        str = str.Replace("</fragment>", "  ");
        str = str.Replace("<hilight>", "<Run Foreground=\"Gold\" FontWeight=\"ExtraBold\" FontSize=\"13\">");
        str = str.Replace("</hilight>", "</Run>");

        str = "<RichTextBox xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"><Paragraph>"
            + str
            + "</Paragraph></RichTextBox>";

        return XamlReader.Load(str);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

BTW, drop your `Mode=TwoWay` on the binding, it isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks Anthony but unfortunately I did use the paragraph tag. When I attempt to render the control I receive the following error: Cannot add instance of type 'System.String' to a collection of type 'System.Windows.Documents.BlockCollection

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to Anthony for helping me work through this. The issue on my part was in fact related to the paragraph tags. While I did insert them originally I had them in the wrong location.

Listed below is the updated code

```
public class HighlightConverter : IValueConverter
{
    ///<summary>
    ///Converter class used to evaluate and highlight context string results
    ///</summary>
    ///
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string str = value.ToString();

        str = str.Replace("&", "&amp;");
        str = str.Replace("<fragment>", "<Paragraph>");
        str = str.Replace("</fragment>", "</Paragraph>");
        str = str.Replace("<hilight>", "<Run Foreground=\"Gold\" FontWeight=\"ExtraBold\" FontSize=\"13\">");
        str = str.Replace("</hilight>", "</Run>");
        return XamlReader.Load("<RichTextBox xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" TextWrapping=\"Wrap\" >" + str + "</RichTextBox>");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Minus a little formatting in the UI this works great.